# Где ошибка? Результатом работы должно быть число

Tags: python, numpy, матрицы

Надо решить уравнение динамической системы, которая описывается следующим образом (случай дискретного времени)
`x = A * x + B * U`.
Цель состоит в том, чтобы минимизировать функцию стоимости `res`
для следующей задачи оптимизации: `res= min(x.T * Q *x + U.T * R * U)`

В результате должны получить число.
А у меня выходит матрица.

Помогите, где ошибка?

```
import numpy as np
    
T = 5
n = 3
m = 2
    
x0 = np.random.rand(n, 1)
A = np.random.rand(n, n)
B = np.random.rand(n, m)
Q = np.random.rand(n, n)
R = np.random.rand(m, m)
H = np.random.rand(n, n)
    
u = np.random.rand(T * m)
    
def Obj(u):
    U = u.reshape((T, m))
    res = 0
    x = x0
    for t in range(T - 1):
        x = A @ x + B @ U[t, :]
        res += x.T @ Q @ x + U[t, :].T @ R @ U[t, :]
        x = A @ x + B @ U[T - 1, :]
        res += x.T @ H @ x
    
    return res
    
result = Obj(u)
    
print("Result:", result)
```

Comment: 1) Поправьте отступы, 2) `return np.min(res)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть для этого `x0` должно быть вектором, а не матрицей размерности (n,1)?

```py
x0 = np.random.rand(n)
```

Так на выходе получается число.

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое, добрый человек!!